# Reset css property value ?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a page which uses a css file which has

```
html 
{
 width:100%;
}
```

However  when  that page in  `Iframe` - it  causes `x-scroll`.

[image]

But - If I remove the `width` attribute ( via chrome developer toolbar)  OR set an invalid value like `''` - it's getting fine :

[image]

**Question  :**

Is it Ok to do this : ( in order to reset the value)

```
<head  >
      /*The original css file - I dont want to touch it*/
       <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Css/style.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    html
    {
        width: '' !important;
    }
    </style>
```

p.s.

No js solutions please.

Comment: set __margin__ and __padding__ as 0

Comment: @Pranavc not working. http://i.stack.imgur.com/MCunf.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reset that value you have to use the default one for `width`:

```
html
{
    width:auto;
}
```

Also is not necessary to use the `!important` declaration.

Comment: Regarding your second line , you said it becuase it comes "after" the original declaration( so it will win) ...right?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Is correct if the other style is called by a CSS file or comes "before" this one isn't necessary the important